# Calling C# COM Object from javascript fails

Tags: javascript, c#, html, com

I'm trying to call a COM C# Object from javascript code and get an object that doesn't contain the COM object functions. 
I created a setup project for the C# COM library. The library is signed for COM interop, and the setup project output is signed for COM register on the machine it deployed at. 
I see that the TLB is properly exported. 
**C# Code:**

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace YaronTestCOM
{
    [Guid("BD145EEC-ACAC-4FDB-B766-0F15CE07990F")]
    [ComVisible(true)]
    [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
    [ComSourceInterfaces(typeof(IComEvents))]
    public class YaronComObject : IComObject, IObjectSafety
    {
       [ComVisible(false)]
       public delegate void YaronFirstEventHandler(string args);

       public event YaronFirstEventHandler YaronFirstEvent;

       public int YaronFirstComCommand(string arg)
       {
          if (YaronFirstEvent != null)
              YaronFirstEvent(arg);
          return (int)DateTime.Now.Ticks;
       }

       public void Dispose()
       {
       }
    }

    [Guid("A3576AA4-9DE0-422D-BAA3-3FFB862E8007")]
    [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual)]
    [ComVisible(true)]
    public interface IComObject
    {
       [DispId(0x10000001)]
       int YaronFirstComCommand(string arg);

       [DispId(0x10000002)]
       void Dispose();
     }

     [Guid("B551EC8B-4D19-4781-938C-9E50E70D37CD")]
     [ComVisible(true)]
     [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIDispatch)]
     public interface IComEvents
     {
         [DispId(0x00000001)]
         void YaronFirstEvent(string args);
     }
 }
```

**HTML+Javascrip Code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <object id="publisher" name="publisher" classid="clsid:BD145EEC-ACAC-4FDB-B766-0F15CE07990F"></object>
    <title>Sender Test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var msgTxt = $("#msgTxt");

            $("#btnSend").click(function () {
                var msg = msgTxt.val();
                //publisher.YaronFirstComCommand is undefined!!!
                var result = publisher.YaronFirstComCommand(msg);

                alert('The message ' + msg + 'has been sent and returned ' + result);
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <input type='text' id='msgTxt' />
        <input type='button' value='Send Message' id='btnSend' />
    </div>
</body>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Although it is technically possible to call a COM library from Javascript, I would recommend calling a REST service instead

Comment: If I understand right, you are setting publisher using the classID, but the class does not publish the function. I would try using the GUID of the interface, or sending a queryUInterface with it to the instance of the class, in order to get an interface that publishes the function